# I can't access my C ++ program file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Initially, I could access my code. But then after adding github into the visual studio 2019, I couldn't able to access my cpp file.

I have tried accessing by solution explorer.

[image]

I can run and compile even I can debug but I can't see the code.

[image]

Also, whenever I try to access anything from team explorer or try to use git, visual studio 2019 gets stuck. Only if I create a new project, then I can access that new cpp. But not the previous one I was working on. Sometimes it shows unable to start the program.

[image]

Comment: Try to delete the `.vs` folder in your project directory, and reopen the `.sln` solution file. Does it work?

Comment: It worked, but not directly, after deleting the .vs folder and reopened it, then need to find the cpp from solution explorer and then it shows up finally. Thanks a lot.